# Why aren't my CartoDB map layers loading?

Tags: visualisation, carto, publishing

We have built our own instance of CartoDB on our servers, setup production environtment successfully. We can upload shape files, table and map view works great.

When we trying to create visualization with two different data and publish, CartoDB generates a short url. But when we try to access the visualization (sharing) through that short url none of the layer gets displayed on map. The basemap loads fine, but the layers don't appear.

I could see the following error message on console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://cartodb.com/noneuser.html
```

I really don't know what's wrong, could someone can help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what the short URL expands to? Does that longer URL exist?

Comment: Yes, its expanding to correct host (to the instance we have) with correct viz id. Base maps are coming, but layers not loading.

Comment: It sounds like the short url is a red herring and the issue is that, while your private URLs work fine, map layers aren't loading on public URLs and you're getting what sounds like a permissions error. More questions: does this problem only happen when you have more than one data set? That is, can you publish and share maps with just one data set? Start simple and work your way out.

Comment: @Amanda Thanks for the suggestion. Nope, with just one data set also the same problem. In both case I could see layer(s) in visualization screen, layer(s) displayed in preview area ("Publish your visualization") while publishing. But when we access the short url only base map gets displayed.

Comment: When running in development mode, everything works fine. But in production mode, layers not loading in shared link.  When I tried to precompile them assets for production environment byy executing following code:  `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I got the following error `AssetSync: using /opt/cartodb2.0/cartodb/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb rake aborted! Fog provider can't be blank, Fog directory can't be blank`. Does that error causing this issue?

Comment: Instead of fetching tiles from our server it's trying to fetch from `1.api.cartocdn.com/user/tiles/layergroup/0e247253b0b9b00130c59608de9ab4d2:0/13/5924/3797.png`. any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: I don't know the solution, but if I were you I'd revise your question to reflect what you've described in the comments -- and consider posting it to Stack Exchange, since this sounds like it is less about GIS and more about server configuration.

Comment: This is purely about cartodb configuration, that is why posted here & tagged catodb. Now, I revise the question and post in CartoDB google groups.